# Bash: Creating a shell variable in a bash script that I can access from command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have very little experience working with bash. With that being said I need to create a bash script that takes your current directory path and saves it to a shell variable. I then need to be able to type "echo $shellvariable" and have that output the directory that I saved to that variable in the bash script. This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
mypath=$(pwd)
cd $1
echo $mypath
exec bash
```

now when I go to command line and type "echo $mypath" it outputs nothing.

Comment: Could be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Can you explain how you would use this variable?

Comment: Running this script normally starts a new shell in a subprocess (or, more precisely, when you run this script it runs as a subprocess, and the `exec` turns that subprocess into a new interactive shell). That new shell will be missing any (non-`export`ed) variables from the original shell (along with any special modes set in that shell). If you run the script five times, you'll wind up 5 levels deep in subprocesses. Then, as you exit those shells it'll drop back to the parent shells one level by one. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `export` the variable for it to exist in the newly-`exec`ed shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
export mypath=$(pwd)
cd $1
echo $mypath
exec bash
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just run `source <file_with_your_vars>`, this will load your variables in yours script or command line session.

```
> cat source_vars.sh
my_var="value_of_my_var"
> echo $my_var

> source source_vars.sh
> echo $my_var
value_of_my_var
```

Comment: This is generally the best way to have a "script" set variables in an existing shell. Note that the "standard" command to do this is `.` (yes, a period is a valid command), but some shells like bash allow `source` as a synonym (with some subtle differences).

Answer (score 0):

### Hello

'env -i' gives control what vars a shell/programm get...

```
#!/bin/bash
mypath=$(pwd)
cd $1
echo $mypath
env -i mypath=${mypath} exec bash
```

...i.e. with minimal environment.